# Testing react components with Cypress + react-query

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-query

I would like to perform a unit test (with Cypress) on my react component. Inside the component, I use to communicate with API a useMutation function. Are there any methods to mock in tests the answer from API?

Example test:

I'm checking the checkbox, after that the button should be enable.

The problem is that the checkbox in the component is downloaded from API so no checkbox appears.